# Noun suffix with -ing or -tion

Tags: word-choice, suffixes

Which of the following words is correct and why?

> This helps **discriminating/discrimination** of objects...

Comment: This helps to discriminate objects?

Comment: *This helps **in the** discrimination of objects*? (I can't think of any minor rephrasing that would make *discriminating* sound natural.)

Comment: _This helps with discriminating objects_ sounds natural to me, @JasonBassford. (Though it potentially has another meaning)

Comment: As commenters note, one or more words need to be inserted to make it a correct sentence. Another possibility: "This helps to discriminate between objects."

Answer (score 1):

*X-ion*/*X-tion*/*X-sion*/*X-ation* leans toward meaning the result/effect of an action X.  As actions are typically done to achieve results, *-ion* words are often used to talk about both.

*X-ing* leans toward meaning the actual action X not necessarily connected to an end or result.  You may use this if the action is not expected to be completed, or is being talked about abstractly.

> The configuring is the most difficult part.

Here, *configuring* is probably part of a process that will be repeated over and over.  We are talking about *configuring* abstractly and not an instance of actual configuring which will be expected to be completed.

> The configuration is the most difficult part.

Here, configuring is probably something you have to do, and it will be difficult, but you are expected to actually perform it and complete it, resulting in a *configuration*.